# Some C/C++ syntax

Tags: c++, c

I have done some searching, but didn't find the answer 
The code:

```
char b = 'b';
char c = 'c';
char a[5] = "";
a[0] = b, c;
```

What last line means? The b, c part?

Thank you all

Comment: `a[0] = b, c;` This will assign `c` to `a[0]`. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, it won't.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It evaluates `a[0] = b` and discards the result, then evaluates `c` and discards the result.

Comment: @hvd Ah yes, you're right! Operator precedence ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That uses the elusive [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) to cause confusion.

It evaluates `b`, and result of that is then asssigned to `a[0]`. After that, `c` is evaluated but its value thrown away. At least this is the case in C.

The comma has lower precedence than assignment ([see this handy table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)) which is extra confusing.

Comment: , has lowest precedence...

Comment: -1 because the LHS of `,` is `a[0] = b`, and the RHS is `c`.

Comment: I had it wrong first, but I double-checked since I got cautious, corrected and linked in the reference material.

Comment: Yes b is assigned to a[0] but are you sure c is evaluated last? I think that is undefined if the comma is not operator-overloaded.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg I forgot to mention that my answer applies to C only.

Comment: @unwind, I looked in the reference and it is actually left to right in C++ too. I wonder since when or I just dreamed it was the other way round once. Or it was only in parameter lists.